# I am new to Xcode, I'm attempting to change the background color of my project

Tags: swift, colors

this is the code of my GameScene.swift:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

  // 1
  let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "pointer")

  override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
      // 2
  backgroundColor = SKColor.redColor()
      // 3
  player.position = CGPoint( x: size.height * 0.5, y: size.width * 0.1)
      // 4
      addChild(player)
  }
}
```

I'm trying to change it to red and nothing occurs, also I would like to know how to change it to any color, even a more specific ones.

Comment: What version of Xcode do you use? Have you created a blank game project using Xcode wizard with SpriteKit selected as a game technology? Do you compile for Mac OS X or for iOS?

Comment: I've got Xcode 7, I started a new game project with spritekit and swift, also I compile for IOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UIColor instead of SKColor.

```
backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

UIColor has several properties. Just use `UIColor.` and begin typing the name of the color you want. If it is not there, use `UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)` to create the color you want. Hope this helps.

Comment: As you can see with this screenshot: http://prntscr.com/aco6g7  and  http://prntscr.com/aco6z0 I updated the code but when i play the simulation it remains white,  I'm new to Xcode so is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Just to make sure, right now you have set the breakpoint on the same line where you have the color change in case of backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor(). If you pass the breakpoint and return to normal app execution, it doesn't change to red then?

Comment: @sky1cap there are break points in your code. See those dark blue things on the left edge of your code? You must have accidentally tapped those. Tao them again and the will turn light blue, meaning they are removed. Breakpoint stop code. That is why your code isn't running. Remove them and you will be fine.

Comment: @invisible_hand and Penatheboss Thank you so much, that was it! Sorry, I'm new to Xcode as I said

Comment: @penatheboss  So I was able to change the color however when I input specific values they don't work, if add the blue value it becomes blue if I ad the green value it overrides the blues color and turns green, when I ad red it becomes white.    here is my code: let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "pointer")
    
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        // 2
        backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 140, green: 252, blue: 192, alpha: 1)
        // 3
        player.position = CGPoint( x: size.height * 0.29, y: size.width * 0.25)
        // 4

Comment: Yes. That does look like it should work. Glad I could help you solve your problem. Good luck

Comment: One small change however; the 140 or 252 or 192 should all be replaced with 140/225 or 252/255 or 192/225. This is because the red green and blue must be between 0 and 1